# AI learning to drive (simplistic) needing optimisation

Tags: python, performance, genetic-algorithm

So I have done a little program where the goal is trying to teach some cars (red and blue rectangles) to "drive" through genetic algorithm. It works well and I haven't seen any bugs, but the program is painfully slow. As I am pretty much a begginner, I am sure there are tons of things that could be improved.

The cars can either stay straight or turn right/left 1 degree. If they touch a black line (called death_lines in the program) they "die".  The collision detection is according to whether the two diagonals of the rectangle/car touch a certain line.

The cars are defined by three points and an angle. The blue cars are the ones who did the best in the previous generation.

The fitness funtion is calculated according to how many green lines (called checkpoints in the program) the car passed and the distance to the center of the next chekpoint. The part of the neural networks are, well, like most neural network. But I did it from scratch, so any improvement would also be greatly apreciated.

These is more or less the whole program described, the rest should be understandable on its own. Please feel free to ask any doubth about the program. I want to specify that I thought of using batches, but it would slow down the process and the whole point of this is to make it as quick as possible. One thing I already added was to take decissions only half of the time, and the other half using the decission made previously.

Here is the code (uses the Python 3 and the Pygame library):

main.py:

```py
import pygame
import random
from neuron import Population
from car import Car

def sortBests(elem):
    return elem[1]

class Population_cars:
    def __init__(self, PopNumber,id=0,prevBest=[]):


        self.id=id

        self.initialnumber=PopNumber
        self.still_alive=PopNumber
        self.actual_score=0

        self.death_records=[]

        self.death_lines=[
            [[200, 100], [600, 100],[900, 300],[850, 600],[560, 340],[250, 340],[250,390],[480,390],[500,530],[520,350],[850, 610]],
            [[200, 250], [600, 250],[750, 300],[750, 400],[600, 290],[200, 290],[200,460],[400,460],[520,650],[560,450],[850, 650]]
        ]


        self.checkpoints=[[self.death_lines[0][i],self.death_lines[1][i]] for i in range(len(self.death_lines[0]))]

        self.brains= Population(PopNumber,[5,4,4,3],prevBest)
        self.population=[]
        for i in range(PopNumber):
            self.population.append(Car(self.brains.population[i]))
        while True:
            self.actual_score+=1

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            self.draw()

            deleted=0
            for i in range(len(self.population)):
                car=self.population[i-deleted]

                car.advance_car()

                car.takeDecision(self.death_lines)

                if car.detectCollision(self.death_lines,self.checkpoints):
                    self.death_records.append((car.brain,car.fitness(self.checkpoints)))
                    self.still_alive-=1
                    self.population.pop(i-deleted)
                    deleted+=1

            if self.still_alive==0:
                self.nextGeneration()



            pygame.display.flip()

    def draw(self, color_car=(255, 0, 0)):
        global screen
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for car in self.population:
            if not car.isAlive:
                continue
            full_car = car.positions.copy()
            last_x = full_car[2][0] + (full_car[0][0] - full_car[1][0])
            last_y = full_car[2][1] + (full_car[0][1] - full_car[1][1])
            full_car.append([last_x, last_y])
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color_car, full_car, 0)
            #pygame.draw.circle(screen,[0,0,0],tuple(map(int,car.getCenter())),100,1)
        for death_line in self.death_lines:
            for i in range(len(death_line) - 1):
                pygame.draw.line(screen, [0, 0, 0], death_line[i], death_line[i+1], 3)
        for check_line in self.checkpoints:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, [100, 200, 100], check_line[0], check_line[1], 1)



    def nextGeneration(self):
        global pop
        self.death_records.sort(key=sortBests)
        thisBests = self.death_records[-5:]
        print(thisBests)
        pop=Population_cars(self.initialnumber,self.id+1,thisBests)










        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



WINDOW_WIDTH = 1500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 750
WINDOW_SIZE = [WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT]


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Car AI")

pop=Population_cars(100)
```

car.py:

```py
import math

def ccw(A, B, C):
    return (C[1] - A[1]) * (B[0] - A[0]) > (B[1] - A[1]) * (C[0] - A[0])


def intersect(A, B, C, D):
    return ccw(A, C, D) != ccw(B, C, D) and ccw(A, B, C) != ccw(A, B, D)


def point_intersect(A, B, C, D):
    first_vector = (B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1])
    second_vector = (D[0] - C[0], D[1] - C[1])

    dist_x = (A[0] - C[0]) / (second_vector[0] - first_vector[0])
    dist_y = (A[1] - C[1]) / (second_vector[1] - first_vector[1])

    x = A[0] + first_vector[0] * dist_x
    y = A[1] + first_vector[1] * dist_y
    return (x, y)

def dist_intersect(A, B, C, D,reach):
    if not intersect(A,B,C,D):
        #print("flag",A,B,C,D)
        return 1

    first_vector = (B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1])
    second_vector = (D[0] - C[0], D[1] - C[1])


    dist_x = (A[0] - C[0]) / (second_vector[0] - first_vector[0])
    dist_y = (A[1] - C[1]) / (second_vector[1] - first_vector[1])

    x = first_vector[0] * dist_x
    y = first_vector[1] * dist_y

    output = (x**2+y**2)**0.5

    return 1-output/reach-0.1

class Car:
    def __init__(self,brain):
        #self.positions=[[300, 300], [300, 360], [320, 360]]
        #self.positions=[[200, 160], [200, 220], [220, 220]]
        self.positions=[[260, 160], [260, 180], [200, 180]]
        self.angle=0
        self.isAlive=True
        self.brain=brain

        self.checkpoints_passed=1

    def getCenter(self):
        return [(self.positions[0][0] + self.positions[2][0]) / 2, (self.positions[0][1] + self.positions[2][1]) / 2]
    def advance_car(self, speed=1):
        advance_x = math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))
        advance_y = math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))
        # print(angle,advance_x,advance_y)
        for point in self.positions:
            point[0] += advance_x * speed
            point[1] -= advance_y * speed

    def turn_car(self,turn):
        self.angle-=turn
        center = self.getCenter()
        for i in self.positions:
            i[0] -= center[0]
            i[1] -= center[1]

            i[0] = i[0] * math.cos(math.radians(turn)) - i[1] * math.sin(math.radians(turn))
            i[1] = i[0] * math.sin(math.radians(turn)) + i[1] * math.cos(math.radians(turn))

            i[0] += center[0]
            i[1] += center[1]

    def detectCollision(self, death_lines, checklines):
        last_x = self.positions[2][0] + (self.positions[0][0] - self.positions[1][0])
        last_y = self.positions[2][1] + (self.positions[0][1] - self.positions[1][1])

        nextCheck=checklines[self.checkpoints_passed]
        if intersect(self.positions[0], self.positions[2], nextCheck[0], nextCheck[1]) or intersect(self.positions[1], (last_x,last_y), nextCheck[0], nextCheck[1]):
            self.checkpoints_passed+=1
        for death_line in death_lines:
            if self.checkpoints_passed>1:
                intersect_prev=intersect(self.positions[0], self.positions[1], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-2], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-1]) or intersect(self.positions[2], (last_x,last_y), death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-2], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-1])
            else:
                intersect_prev=False
            intersect_next=intersect(self.positions[0], self.positions[1], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-1], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed]) or intersect(self.positions[2], (last_x,last_y), death_line[self.checkpoints_passed-1], death_line[self.checkpoints_passed])
            if intersect_next or intersect_prev:
                self.isAlive=False
                self.deathPoint=self.positions[0]
                return True
        return False

    def range_points(self,leng):
        center=self.getCenter()
        output=[]

        for i in range(-2,3):
            ang=self.angle+i*30
            x,y=math.cos(math.radians(ang))*leng , math.sin(math.radians(ang))*leng
            output.append((int(center[0]+x),int(center[1]-y)))

        return output
    def collision_distances(self,death_lines,reach):
        center=self.getCenter()
        #print(self.range_points())
        out=[]
        for A in self.range_points(reach):
            add=1
            for death_line in death_lines:
                for i in range(len(death_line)-1):
                    add=min(add,dist_intersect(A,center,death_line[i],death_line[i+1],reach))
            out.append(add)
        return out

    def takeDecision(self,death_lines=None,reach=100):

        data=self.collision_distances(death_lines,reach)
        decision=self.getMaxResult(self.brain.feedAll(data))
        if decision==1:
            self.turn_car(1)
        elif decision==2:
            self.turn_car(-1)

    def fitness(self,checkpoints):
        line_to_reach=checkpoints[self.checkpoints_passed]
        point_to_reach=((line_to_reach[0][0]+line_to_reach[1][0])/2,(line_to_reach[0][1]+line_to_reach[1][1])/2)

        distance_to_point=((point_to_reach[0]-self.deathPoint[0])**2+(point_to_reach[1]-self.deathPoint[1])**2)**0.5

        #print(self.checkpoints_passed , distance_to_point, (self.checkpoints_passed*10)**2-distance_to_point*10)
        return (self.checkpoints_passed*1000)-distance_to_point
    def getMaxResult(self,results):
        return results.index(max(results))
```

neuron.py:

````py
import random
import math
import copy
"""
def sigmoid(x):
    return .5 * (math.tanh(.5 * x) + 1)"""
def sigmoid(x):
    if x<-100:
        return 0
    if x>100:
        return 1
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-4.9*x))

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self,num_outputs, neuronindex,weights=[]):
        self.outputWeights=[]
        self.neuronIndex= neuronindex

        for i in range(num_outputs):
            if i<len(weights):
                self.outputWeights.append(weights[i])
            else:
                self.outputWeights.append(random.uniform(-1,1))
    def getOutputWeight(self,i):
        return self.outputWeights[i]
    def getOutputFromInputs(self,inputs,inputWeights):
        output=0
        for i in range(len(inputWeights)):
            output+=inputs[i]*inputWeights[i]
        if output<-200:
            print(inputs,inputWeights)
        return sigmoid(output)
class Net:
    def __init__(self,topology=[],model=False):
        self.topolgy = topology
        if model!=False:
            self.layers=model.layers.copy()
        else:
            self.layers=[]
            for i in range(len(topology)-1):
                layer=[]
                numOutputs=topology[i+1]
                for neuronNum in range(topology[i]):
                    layer.append(Neuron(numOutputs,neuronNum))
                self.layers.append(layer)
            layer = []
            for i in range(topology[-1]):
                layer.append(Neuron(0,i))
            self.layers.append(layer)
    def feedLayer(self,inputs,layerNum):
        layer=self.layers[layerNum]
        outputs=[]
        for i in range(len(layer)):
            neuronWeights=[]
            for a in self.layers[layerNum-1]:
                neuronWeights.append(a.getOutputWeight(i))
            outputs.append(layer[i].getOutputFromInputs(inputs,neuronWeights))
        return outputs
    def feedAll(self,inputs):
        prevOutputs=inputs.copy()
        for i in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            prevOutputs=self.feedLayer(prevOutputs,i)
        return prevOutputs
class Population:
    def __init__(self,PopNumber,topology=[],bestResults=[]):
        self.topology=topology
        if len(bestResults)>=1:
            self.population=[]
            for i,score in bestResults:
                self.population.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
            prev_brains=[item[0] for item in bestResults]
            prev_results=[item[1] for item in bestResults]
            num_mutate=PopNumber-len(bestResults)
            random_chosen=random.choices(population=prev_brains, weights=prev_results, k=num_mutate)
            for addNet in random_chosen:
                mutation = self.mutate(addNet)
                self.population.append(mutation)
            for i in range(PopNumber-num_mutate-len(bestResults)):
                combination=self.combine(random.sample(bestResults, 2))
                self.population.append(combination)


        else:
            self.population=[]
            for i in range(PopNumber):
                self.population.append(Net(self.topology))

    def choose(self,options):
        output=[]
        numChosen=random.randint(1,len(options))
        for i in range(numChosen):
            output.append(options[random.randint(0,len(options)-1)])
        return output

    def combine(self,chosen):
        output= copy.deepcopy(chosen[0])
        for layer in range(len(output.layers)-1):
            for neuron in range(len(output.layers[layer])):
                for weight in range(self.topology[layer+1]):
                    if random.randint(0,10)>=5:
                        output.layers[layer][neuron].outputWeights[weight]=copy.copy(chosen[1].layers[layer][neuron].outputWeights[weight])
        return output
    def mutate(self,chosen):
        output=copy.deepcopy(chosen)
        for layer in output.layers[:-1]:
            for neuron in layer:
                for weight in range(len(neuron.outputWeights)):
                    rand=random.randint(1,10)
                    if rand==1:
                        neuron.outputWeights[weight]=random.uniform(-1,1)
                    else:
                        neuron.outputWeights[weight] += random.gauss(0,1)/50
                        if neuron.outputWeights[weight]>1:
                            neuron.outputWeights[weight]=1
                        elif neuron.outputWeights[weight]<-1:
                            neuron.outputWeights[weight]=1
        return output

```
````

Comment: In your testing, do the red cars ever make it around the bottom-most turn?

Comment: No, they didn’t. I thought it was just a matter of leaving it for long. Precisely I thought it would be useful to optimize it first before adding more circuits or more complex ones.